# How to make the player pass through only certain objects, but not others?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-physics

Experimenting with my 1st Unity project. It's about a top down swimmer. By toggling the swimmer's collider, he can swim under boats:

```
if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.A)) swimmerCircleCollider.enabled = !swimmerCircleCollider.enabled;
```

At the same time I don't want him to be able to swim under the wharf, which is like an uncrossable barrier/border/wall or simply the end of playable area. How can I achieve that?

Is the idea of disabling the collider wrong in the first place? If so, please provide some guidelines for a better solution.

Comment: look at physics layers.

Comment: -> [Layer-based Collision Detection](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/LayerBasedCollision.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use exclude layers, either on the Rigidbody or the Collider of the player, I can try and explain how to do this but I may not be 100% on everything. Of course let me know if you have any issues and I can try to help. Anyway,

**Step 1:**

Select the ship gameobject, or prefab if your spawning them. And find the layer dropdown at the top. [image: layer dropdown]

Now click on it and press add layer, in one of the user layers write a name for the layer (for example, "ship") and then go back onto the ship gameobject and select it as the layer. Also note the layer number, which will be displayed for all layers when you select it.

[image]

**Step 2:**

Now inside of the script, we need to reference this layer, there are 2 ways of doing this, for a cleaner method you can reference a layer as an int, and set it to the layer number from earlier. As an example ill use layer 4, which as you can see above, is water.

```
private int waterLayer = 4;
```

Alternatively, if you want to use multiple layers, you can provide a layermask that you can edit in the inspector by making it public.

```
public LayerMask shipLayer;
```

Now to toggle between being able to pass through we can modify the exludeLayers property of a Rigidbody or collider, since you use a circle collider before, ill show you how to apply it:

```
// get a reference
private CircleCollider2D collider;
public LayerMask shipLayer;
// OR
private int shipLayerInt = 6;
// bool to control whether we can go through ships
private bool goThroughShips = false;

// assign the collider to the collider present on the object
void Start() {
    collider = GetComponent<CircleCollider2D>();
}

// toggle
void Update() {
    // toggle the value
    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.A)) goThroughShips = !goThroughShips;
    if (goThroughShips) {
        // for information on what << means, see the docs
        // https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/layermask-set.html
        collider.excludeLayers = 1 << shipLayerInt
        // OR
        collider.excludeLayers = shipLayer;
    }
    else {
        // creating a new layermask defaults it to none
        collider.excludeLayers = new LayerMask();
    }
```

Hopefully this fixes your problem :)

Comment: Another way of doing it would be with ```Physics2D.IgnoreLayerCollision(int layer, int layer2, bool ignore);```

Comment: You forgot to add ```swimmerCircleCollider.excludeLayers = 1 >> boatsLayerNo;``` inside ```else``` statement, but it works :)

Comment: I can't put the ```LayerMask``` solution to work.

Comment: "You forgot to add swimmerCircleCollider.excludeLayers = 1 >> boatsLayerNo; inside else" Thats what this line is for: collider.excludeLayers = new LayerMask();

Comment: What is the part `private int waterLayer = 4;` needed for?

Comment: and yes, ignore layercollision works, but doesn't allow you to have multiple layers.

Comment: the waterlayer is if you don't want to use a layermask. With a private int it can be less messy since you don't have to assign it in the editor.

Comment: So `collider.excludeLayers = 1 << shipLayerInt` works with `collider.excludeLayers = 1 >> shipLayerInt` and `collider.excludeLayers = new LayerMask();`, while `collider.excludeLayers = shipLayer;` works only with `collider.excludeLayers = new LayerMask();`. I get it now.

Comment: You mean `private int waterLayer = 4;` is the same as `private int shipLayerInt = 6;` with the difference that Water layer exists by default and there's no need to add a user layer.

Comment: _`IgnoreLayerCollision` doesn't allow you to have multiple layers_ 

What do you mean by that? I have multiple layers and `IgnoreLayerCollision` works, too.

Comment: 1. yes, where ive added the `//OR` is trying to show you can pick between either method. 2. I added waterLayer as an example, for example if your ship layer is layer 7 you would set it to 7. 3. If ignoreLayerCollision works, use it. But I'm only familiar with excludeLayers.